# javascript ternary operator opposed to if/else

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am trying to write this if/else statement using javascript's ternary operator syntax. Is it possible to write this as a ternary operator?

```
function changePlayer() {
            if (currentPlayer === playerOne) {
                currentPlayer = playerTwo
            } else {
                currentPlayer = playerOne
            }
        };
```

My current attempt is:

```
function changePlayer(){
      currentPlayer === playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
}
```

Comment: `currentPlayer=[playerOne, playerTwo][+(currentPlayer==playerOne)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just miss the assignment statement. So the final example will go like this:

```
function changePlayer(){
      currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === playerOne) ? playerTwo : playerOne;
}
```

Comment: nice! will give you the `green tick` when I can

Comment: I'd say he misses the assignment.

Comment: I think you meant the assignment. The comparison wasn't missing.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald There was nothing wrong with the code, it was just the explanation that needed a tweak.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the ternary operator is the condition:

```
function changePlayer(){
  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === playerOne) ? playerTwo : playerOne;
}
```